# Problem merging/sorting arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 arrays like so, that can contain an infinite number of items:

```
Weight Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 250 [2] => 400 )
Price Array ( [0] => 1.20 [1] => 6.00 [2] => 9.50 )
Courier Array ( [0] => DHL [1] => DHL [2] => UPS )
```

I'd like to merge them and sort them like so:

```
    Array (
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 1.20
        [2] => DHL
        [3] => 250
        [4] => 6.00
        [5] => DHL
        [6] => 400
        [7] => 9.50
        [8] => UPS
    )
```

Is there a built in PHP function that does this or will I have to write my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need in function, I suppose:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($WeightArray); $i++) {
  $TargetArray[] = $WeightArray[$i];
  $TargetArray[] = $PriceArray[$i];
  $TargetArray[] = $CourierArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer, as the others recommend array_merge which does not work as requested by the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed one built-in.

https://www.php.net/array_merge

Comment: array_merge just appends each array to the end of the previous one, I want to sort them too.

Comment: ah sorry. read too fast. you don't really want to sort them, you just want to use element 0 from array 0, element 0 from array 1, element 0 from array, element 0 from array 1...

So to me it looks like you want to keep track of the corresponding weights, prices, and couriers. Why not use objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

This should do the trick, you can add as many parameters as you want to add more arrays.